# Normal User requires Admin approval to register in Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel-5

In my Laravel project I want to add an admin approval form users to successfully register.
Currently I have a boolean column in my users table which is assigned to false by default.
When a user registers, it displays a message "thank you for registration... Wait for approval."
I can use the "PHP artisan tinker" to manually change the boolean to true, however, I want the admin to approve from the admin dashboard.
In my admin dashboard under user list page I can display two tables, one for the approved users another for the not approved once.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div id="wrapper" class="active">

   <!-- Sidebar -->
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul id="sidebar_menu" class="sidebar-nav">
     <li class="sidebar-brand">menu</li>
    </ul>
   @include('includes.admin-sidebar')
</div>

<!-- Page content -->
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
<!-- Keep all page content within the page-content inset div! -->
<div class="page-content inset">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      @foreach ($users as $user)
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Date Created</th>
            <th>Approve Login</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->created_at}}</td>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="approveUser()">Approve</button></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      @endforeach
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      @foreach ($usersApproved as $userap)
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Date Created</th>
            <th>Approve Login</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>{{$userap->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$userap->email}}</td>
            <td>{{$userap->created_at}}</td>
            <td>{{$userap->loginapproval}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      @endforeach
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
@endsection
```

I have added a button to the not approved table. I want to click it to change the value of approval from true to false.

Answer (score 0):

To continue on your track you just need to implement the approveUser(). But you need to pass a unique identifier (id) to the function as:

```
<td><button type="button" data-user-id="{{$user->id}}" class="btn btn-primary j-approve-user" onclick="approveUser()">Approve</button></td>
```

Then at the bottom of the page add some javascript. If you are using JQuery you can do this:

```
$(".j-approve-user").click(function(){
    var userId = $(this).data('userId');
    $.ajax({url: "/user/approve", type: "POST", success: function(result){
        //show some notification to the user
    }});
});
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. but can you explain a bit what is going on in here? and is there a way to do it without ajax?